# Typescript compilation in Visual Studio vs WebStorm - Do both use Node.js for compilation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, typescript, webstorm

I recently changed from using Visual Studio to try out WebStorm as an IDE for developing an AngularJS / Typescript front-end application.

What I noticed is that Typescript appears to be slower and less well integrated into WebStorm.

Can anyone tell me if the two IDE's compile Typescript in the same way? I believe WebStorm does this through Node.js and I am wondering if this might account for WebStorm feeling a bit slower and giving less intellisense.

Comments from people who have used both IDEs would be very much appreciated.

Comment: WebStorm uses tsc CLI to compile typescript - tsc executable is configured as a file watcher so that editing a .ts file triggers the external compiler. This indeed can be slower than integrating compiler as a service as it's done in VS

Comment: see also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11491

Answer (score 0):

I believe Visual Studio uses Chakra (the IE engine) saw that on codeplex and GitHub a few times.

The Typescript team also creates the VS plugin so I suspect they just have more resources available to also make Typescript super integrated in VS and because they created it they know a lot about using it.

They both use the same languageservice so WebStorm should be able to give it the same experience though.

edit: You see Chakra mentioned here for example: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/995

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's Typescript IntelliSense is powered by Roslyn, running on .NET, so it's not the regular Typescript language service.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-typescript-1-3.aspx

In WebStorm, I believe TypeScript code assistance is powered by the same code assistance tech used throughout their IDEs.  So, again, not the Typescript language service.  It does use node to compile TypeScript, as evidenced by the Preferences dialog where it asks for the path to your node binary.

I'm not sure if you were asking specifically about how the IDEs handle IntelliSense, how they compile .ts to .js, or both.